# how to change my html code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the home page, 
turn to My food photograph,
then click to see the default picture.

But the original photos do not show out.
[enter image description here][1]

This is my work.
http://guzou.github.io/final/
This is the code.
[enter image description here][2]

Please help me!
thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: AFTER clicking My food photograph pictures are coming ....what you are really searching for please explain

Comment: click the food pictures, it will turn to next page. but the pictures cannot come out in the next page. help me please.

Answer (score 0):

As I understands that; after clicking on Sesame Mochi image on http://guzou.github.io/final/, the http://guzou.github.io/final/f14.html page is missing the image; image path are wrong in the code `<img src="14.jpg" usemap="#uimap" height="569" width="850">` or image does not exist on that folder.

Comment: yes, i don't know why. this is my code  https://github.com/guzou/final/blob/master/f14.html can you help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving wrong image name in f14.html page image name are 14_1.jpg and so on etc can you check that whether this image only you need or not on clicking Sesame Mochi[image]

Comment: both are same image?if yes then you can give this image only or just check where you have put the image may be some other place like in different folder